# How to add a patch to luabind?

Tags: build, patch, luabind

Currently I am trying to build a project using boost. But it gives an error message indicating a missing operator.

```
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/osrm-extract.dir/extractor.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/luabind/wrapper_base.hpp:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/back_reference.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/class.hpp:93,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/luabind.hpp:28,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/Project-OSRM-master/Extractor/ScriptingEnvironment.h:29,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/Project-OSRM-master/extractor.cpp:23:
/usr/include/luabind/detail/call_member.hpp:319:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/include/luabind/back_reference.hpp:27:0,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/class.hpp:93,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/luabind.hpp:28,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/Project-OSRM-master/Extractor/ScriptingEnvironment.h:29,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/Project-OSRM-master/extractor.cpp:23:
/usr/include/luabind/wrapper_base.hpp:92:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/include/luabind/function.hpp:10:0,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/class.hpp:94,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/luabind.hpp:28,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/Project-OSRM-master/Extractor/ScriptingEnvironment.h:29,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/Project-OSRM-master/extractor.cpp:23:
/usr/include/luabind/detail/call_function.hpp:326:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/include/luabind/detail/constructor.hpp:12:0,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/class.hpp:96,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/luabind.hpp:28,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/Project-OSRM-master/Extractor/ScriptingEnvironment.h:29,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/Project-OSRM-master/extractor.cpp:23:
/usr/include/luabind/wrapper_base.hpp:92:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/include/luabind/class.hpp:107:0,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/luabind.hpp:28,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/Project-OSRM-master/Extractor/ScriptingEnvironment.h:29,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/Project-OSRM-master/extractor.cpp:23:
/usr/include/luabind/detail/call_member.hpp:319:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/osrm-extract.dir/extractor.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/osrm-extract.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I did some research and found that it is actually a [bug](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/issues/465) in luabind. It says that changing

```
#elif BOOST_PP_ITERATION_FLAGS() == 1
```

with :

```
#else
#if BOOST_PP_ITERATION_FLAGS() == 1
```

Corrects the problem. So I modified the file /usr/include/luabind/wrapper_base.hpp as it says. But it doesn't work.

Later I found that there is a [patch](https://gist.github.com/ObKo/2011636) to correct that problem. But I do not know how to add that patch to luabind. Please tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, boost 1.49, luabind 0.9.1, g++ 4.6.3, and it seems there is an incompatibility between this boost and luabind.

Only for these version though, at the office I've got boost 1.41 and luabind 0.9.0 and they work fine.

**Edit:**

Actually after modifying the 3 files: call_function.hpp, call_member.hpp and wrapper_base.hpp, as described in [the webpage you mentioned](https://gist.github.com/ObKo/2011636). So that:

```
#elif BOOST_PP_ITERATION_FLAGS() == 1
...
#end
```

is replaced to:

```
#else
#if BOOST_PP_ITERATION_FLAGS() == 1
...
#end
#end
```

I was able to compile my luabind programs.

Maybe you forgot to add a second #end ?